# Micro switch replacement in LG CM2630b CD reader

Tags: switches, surface-mount

I'm trying to fix the CD reader in my LG CM2630b Micro Hi-fi System that suddenly stopped working: it doesn't detect when I'm trying to insert a CD.
After disassembling it, I found that the problem is one of the micro switches inside the reader not making contact (tested with the continuity function of the multimeter, I also checked the other two switches present on the board in the photo below).[image: photo of the switch]

I tried googling the board number (A001) and the CD unit number (SDM-01BA) written in the service manual, but without luck, and I don't know the exact name of the switch.[image]

Does someone know where could I find one of those switches, or what should I look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to be something like this:

[C&K Switch/Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/en/product-highlight/c/ck-components/hdp-series-micro-mini-side-actuated-smd-detect-switches)

[image: Switches]